# Are there pairs of consecutive integers with the same sum of factors?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

### Background/Motivation

I was planning to explain Ruth-Aaron pairs to my son, but it took me a few moments to remember the definition.  Along the way, I thought of the mis-definition, a pair of consecutive numbers with the same sum of divisors.  Well, that's actually two definitions, depending on whether you are looking only at proper divisors.  Suppose all divisors.  I quickly found (14,15) which both have a divisor sum (sigma function) of 24.  Some more work provided (206,207) and then a search on OEIS gave sequence A002961.

What about proper divisors only?  (2,3) comes quickly, but then nothing for a while.  Noting that the parity of this value ($\sigma(n) -n$) is the same as that of $n$ unless $n$ is a square or twice a square, any solution pair must include one number of that form.  With that much information in hand, I posted this problem at the reference desk on Wikipedia.  User PrimeHunter determined that there were no solutions up to $10^{12}$, but there were no general responses.

Aside from the parity issue, I haven't found other individual constraints that would filter the candidates--the number of adjacent values identical modulo $p$ for other small primes is at least as great as would be expected by chance, and there are a fair number of pairs that are arithmetically close.

> Other than (2,3), are there pairs of consecutive integers such that $\sigma(n)-n = \sigma(n+1)-(n+1)$?

Comment: "Noting that 2|(sigma(n)-n) unless n is a square or twice a square". This is nonsense, right? (assuming sigma(n) is the sum of the divisors of n...)

Comment: aah you mean 2|sigma(n) unless...

Comment: Yes, I was getting ahead of myself a bit.  Rephrased to emphasize the point I was trying to make.  Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: You've now edited the post to say " the parity of sigma (n) is the same as that of n unless n is a square or twice a square", and this is still wrong (try n=3). Either that or I've misunderstood what you mean by sigma(n) (which you also didn't define, but which usually means the sum of (all) divisors of n).

Comment: @Alan: Instead of saying "the parity of this value (sigma(n)-n) is the same as that of n", why not simply say "2|sigma(n)" as Kevin suggested?

Comment: GP/PARI on my home computer says that there are no solutions up to 2 times 10^16.  (Obviously one could go much further than this if desired.)

Comment: $2|\sigma(n)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad$ there exists an odd prime $p$ such that $ord_p(n)\equiv 1 \mod 2$. This is not related to the condition about squares and double squares.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński ??? There exists an odd prime $p$ such that $o_p(n)\equiv1\pmod2$ if and only if $n$ is neither a square nor twice a square.

Answer (score 7):

You should look at Carl Pomerance's follow-up paper: Ruth-Aaron pairs revisited, [http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper130.pdf](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/PDF/paper130.pdf) .  In his first paper with Erdös they proved a result which showed that the number of RA pairs had asymptotic density 0, but just barely.  In the follow-up Pomerance shows that the the sum of the reciprocals converges (which is much stronger).

Comment: Don't both of these follow easily for the problem at hand, given the observation that at least one of the pairs must be a square or twice a square? Then the density of such integers up to $N$ must be $\ll \sqrt{N}$, so the sum of reciprocals converges by partial summation.

Comment: It seems to me that the condition about squares and double squares is irrelevant (is wrong)--see my earlier remark under the Question..

Comment: @ThomasBloom I think the paper looks at the sum $S(n)$ of the _prime_ factors of $n$. But this thread is about the quantity $\sigma(n)-n$. For the former, see [A039752](https://oeis.org/A039752) and [A006145](https://oeis.org/A006145).

Comment: In other words, the paper of this answer is about Ruth-Aaron pairs with the _correct_ definition, while this thread is about what happens if you _misremember_ the definition using [A001065](https://oeis.org/A001065)(n)=A001065(n+1) instead of [A001414](https://oeis.org/A001414)(n)=A001414(n+1).

Answer (score 4):

The question can be rephrased as asking for sigma(n + 1) = sigma(n) + sigma(1), in line with the "Freshman's Dream."

Comment: I was hoping to see something about this in Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, but no such luck. In B13, he discusses sigma(n + 2) = sigma(n) + 2 (other than twin primes, there are only three solutions under 200,000,000). Perhaps the reference P Haukkanen in Math Student 62 (1993) 166-168 will say something, although the review 94j:11006 is not encouraging. B15 in Guy is about sigma(q) + sigma(r) = sigma(q + r) but the discussion does not head in the direction of the question at hand. 

By the way, I'm the same Gerry as above, just using a different computer.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies that this isn't a complete answer. The condition $\sigma(n+1)=\sigma(n)+1$ means that $\sigma(n),\sigma(n+1)$ are relatively prime. In the question, you've taken care of the divisibility by $2$ part.

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $q>p$ prime. Let $a_{q,p}=a_q=p$ if $q\equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $a_{q,p}=a_q$ equals the order of $q$ modulo $p$ otherwise. If $\nu_q(n)$, the highest power of $q$ dividing $n$ is, $-1$ mod $a_q$, then $p$ divides $\sigma(n)$. So it is necessary that if $q_1,q_2$ are some primes, then one musn't simultaneously have $\nu_{q_1}(n)\equiv -1 \bmod a_{q_1,p}$ and $\nu_{q_2}(n+1)\equiv -1 \bmod a_{q_2,p}$ for any $p,q_1,q_2$.

For example, if $n=q^2$, where $q$ is prime and $1$ mod $3$, then $n+1$ is $2\bmod 4$ and $3$ divides both $\sigma(n), \sigma(n+1)$, so this is an example of $n$ that must be excluded.